# Proof that the union of iterated powersets of a finite set, is a set?

Tags: set-theory, recursion

Let $A_0$ be a finite set, and consider the sets $A_i = A_{i-1} \cup \mathcal{P}(A_{i-1})$ for all $i > 0$, where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes powerset. Does $\bigcup_{j=0}^{\infty} A_j$ exist as a set?

Intuitively, it seems true because each $A_i$ is a finite set, so the class corresponding to the union must be countable. However, I am unsure how to go about proving this from the axioms, since the power set operator is not actually a function, so the definition of $A_i$ does not immediately give a set-theoretic sequence. (It seems reminiscent of the class of hereditarily finite sets $V_\omega$, but I am having trouble finding a *proof* that $V_\omega$ is a set.)

Comment: In either this or the case of $V_\omega,$ you define the sequence using recursion, then use replacement and union to show that the range of the sequence, then the union of the sequence is a set. I'm can't tell from your remark whether recursion on $\omega$ or the use of replacement is the missing piece for you.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I don't see how I can do recursion if I don't have a function, and I don't have a function because I don't have a domain or codomain yet, which have to be sets.

Comment: The power set is a function... a proper class function, but that's no obstacle here. You show by induction on $n\in\omega$ that for each $n$ there is a unique (set) function $f_n$ with domain $n+1$ such that $f_n(0) = A_0$ and $f_n(i+1) = P(f_n(i))$ for all $i<n.$ Then if we take $f(n) = f_n(n),$ this is a function on $\omega$ satisfying $f(0)=A_0$ and $f(n+1) = P(f(n)),$ and is a set by replacement, since $\omega$ is a set. Then, $\cup \operatorname{ran}(f)$ is the union of interest.